# Dynamic input configuration with default values? (error TS2741)

Tags: typescript

So, basically I am trying to create a dynamic configuration for this class. Each configuration value must be set and must be available in the class (see interface Configuration). The user however who is using it doesn't need to define all of the values and can even leave it empty, for the values the user has not set I would like the default values to fill in. The default object must be outside due to exporting it into tests. I can't quite get around how to do this in TypeScript, in JavaScript it is fairly simple though.

Code:

```
interface Configuration {
    valueOne: string;
    valueTwo: string;
    valueThree: string;
}

interface UserConfiguration {
    valueOne?: string;
    valueTwo?: string;
    valueThree?: string;
}

const defaultConfiguration: Configuration = {
    valueOne: '1',
    valueTwo: '2'
};

class Something {
    configuration: Configuration;

    constructor(userConfiguration: UserConfiguration = {}) {
        const configuration: Configuration = {
            ...defaultConfiguration,
            valueThree: '3', // Must be set specifically for the instance, cannot be shared.
            ...userConfiguration
        };
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    print() {
        console.log(this.configuration.valueOne);
        console.log(this.configuration.valueTwo);
        console.log(this.configuration.valueThree);
    }
}

const userConfiguration = {
    valueOne: 'A'
};
const somethingOne = new Something(userConfiguration);
somethingOne.print();

const somethingTwo = new Something();
somethingTwo.print();
```

Error:

```
src/ts.ts:13:7 - error TS2741: Property 'valueThree' is missing in type '{ valueOne: string; valueTwo: string; }' but required in type 'Configuration'.

13 const defaultConfiguration: Configuration = {
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/ts.ts:4:5
    4     valueThree: string;
          ~~~~~~~~~~
    'valueThree' is declared here.
```

I do realise that I could use non-null assertion in the code, but my linting rules prohibit this.

Or if anyone tackles this in another approach I'm all ears!

Comment: not sure if this is out of bounds of the requirements, but would setting `valueThree: undefined` in `defaultConfiguration` work? Might also be possible to set  `valueThree?: string;` in `Configuration` interface?

Comment: @jmunsch No optional properties unfortunately are allowed in the Configuration interface. Otherwise I don't think this question would of existed ;) Regarding the undefined, undefined is not allowed in the Configuration interface, but is in the UserConfiguration interface!

Comment: You could use `defaultConfiguration: Partial<Configuration>` (and you should use that partial type instead of `UserConfiguration`), but then there's no way to know *which* properties were partially set. Probably the best thing is just to use the *inferred* type of the defaults - it will allow extra props, but they're not accessible through the interface anyway.

Comment: Example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2AcwK5RxjCbIDeAUMtcgG5wA2eEA8iBAFzIDOYUoOANxUa9JhAAqAd3Rde-EEJHUxzCQAsoETjz4DhAXwoUEmXsgAmEeHgZgMWXASIkQyALzlldRszY6AcgBGAIAab1VJGS4AgCYAigNhEwY4bm5kAGV0AFsIMHUBLxpkU0d8QmJMLgdsCpdMZJKy+TwEMHQoAAo8bmhap0rXLgAFOChiRgAeAfqqkAA+D3IDAEpikpoC4G4AOjK653nlyk2z5F3Lqxs7WaPXcPPNgHpnn3ENLUCAZjDkV+QAFlemBkAAjFB9UHcAAOEAQwGwCEYDAAnsgYJ1kAUUKBeHAQEhQqUCSB0KCITx1OMIBZdt4npddr1+phDkNMAyaElvEYjEA